# Move single point with keyboard in OpenOffice/LibreOffice Draw

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-draw

Consider a polygon, which has points.
How can I move an individual point, with arrow keys of the keyboard, but not with mouse?

I tried to select a single point and to move it by pressing arrow key, but the whole polygon is moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on the [OpenOffice forums](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=63129):

> 1. Select the polygon
> 2. If not enabled, press F8 to enable the "edit point mode"
> 3. Press Ctrl-TAB: you'll see one of the points selected (the first one considering the order on which the polygon was created).
> 4. Press Ctrl-TAB again and again until you reach the point you want to move
> 5. Now use the arrow keys: only the selected point will move
>
> It works on AOO 4.0